# How can i prevent the form from opening again?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

How can i prevent the form from opening again.I made my application and installed it, however when i click on the icon again the application open once again and so on if i clicked on the icon again, how can i prevent that ?

Comment: Something to consider is many times this arbitrarily limits your users.

Answer (score 5):

Scott Hanselman did a good post on doing this a while back - here's the [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx)

Comment: Of all the solutions posted to this question, this one is the right one if you are working within .NET. This doesn't involve using Mutexes or killing processes and utilizes baked-in functionality providing full control over what needs to be done if an instance is already running. Go with this one. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try Mutex. Here is a good article on the subject:

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2004/08/20/401.aspx

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
   using(Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "Global\\" + appGuid))
   {
      if(!mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Instance already running");
         return;
      }

      Application.Run(new Form1());
   }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `GC.Collection()` here!

Comment: The article linked explains that the GC.Collection() is there to prove that this code is not broken (using keeps the Mutex alive through the collect) -- the collect could be removed.

Comment: @Lou I see, he just copy and paste the code contents from the article without even diagnosing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Checking list of Currently Running Processes.
If It is Duplicated, Kill Self.
This will prevent Multiple Instances.

```
   Process[] pArry = Process.GetProcesses();   //Get Currently Running Processes   
   int Instance_Counter = 0; // To count No. of Instances

  foreach (Process p in pArry) 
       {         
          string ProcessName = p.ProcessName;   
        //Match the Process Name with Current Process (i.e. Check Duplication )
       //If So Kill self
        if(ProcessName == Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)                
         {              
            Instance_Counter++;   
        }    
           } 

    if(Instance_Counter>1)
    {
       //Show Error and Kill Yourself
    }
```

Comment: The problem in this code is that it is possible that the first instance of application is terminated just after the `if` check succeed, so you will end up without any application instance running.

Comment: The same problem still applied because it could be closed just after the `if (Instance_Counter>1)` executed..

Comment: @Jalal Aldeen Saa'd: That's what expected here, Right?? If another instance is opened by user, Display an error like Application is already running and prevent user from opening another window!

Comment: No, here there is a **Race Condition**, that is it, after the `foreach` statement finishes its execution, and after it finds that there is an instance running "`Instance_Counter > 1`", it is possible that user try of running new instance will fails, because at that very time the instance that already founded running could be terminated when the code is executing! `-->`

Comment: `-->` So you will end up showing error message and no instance is running "the old instance just terminated and the new instance wouldn't start because it was found an instance running when code executed but, that instance was terminated before finishes executing the code. this is a race condition that using `Mutex` will ends it.  hope you got it now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way but fixed method of Swanand Purankar's as it mentioned before:

```
//I set Timer's interval to "250", it's personal
//Just don't forget to enable the timer
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var self = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(self.ProcessName))
    {
        if (proc.Id != self.Id)
        {
            proc.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

However with this way you can't set an error. If you want that:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey there opening multiple instances of this process is restricted!", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Still, the user can easily pass this by renaming the program. Using registry can help. But a hacker/developer still can get rid of this. Via using a process monitor.